# Drupal node_type_get_type() and hook_uninstall()

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a module `job_post` which installs `job_post` content type.

In this module I have `hook_unistall()` which calls for [`node_type_delete()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_delete/7) function which removes my content type.

After unistalling process I have errors from Drupal's core module `comment` which fires from [`node_type_delete()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_delete/7) after `module_invoke_all('node_type_delete', $info)`.

Error is the following and repeats 8 times (because of the loop in `comment_node_type_delete()`):

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in comment_node_type_delete()
(line 343 of ....\comment.module).
```

I have this error because `$info` variable in [`node_type_delete()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_delete/7) function is `false`.

My question is, why when my module is installed and when I'm printing `var_dump(node_type_get_type('job_post'))` on any page, I have an object, but when I'm trying to print the same code in my unistall function I get false and this error?

**job_post.install**

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function job_post_install() {
  node_types_rebuild();

  $types = node_type_get_types();
  node_add_body_field($types['job_post']);

  $body_instance = field_info_instance('node', 'body', 'job_post');
  $body_instance['type'] = 'text_summary_or_trimmed';

  field_update_instance($body_instance);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function job_post_uninstall() {
  $instances = field_info_instances('node', 'job_post');
  foreach ($instances as $instance_name => $instance) {
    field_delete_instance($instance);
  }

  // Force rebuild of the node type cache
  // as Clive suggested didn't help
  // _node_types_build(TRUE);

  node_type_delete('job_post');

  field_purge_batch(1000);
}
```

**job_post.module**

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_node_info() to provide our job_post type.
 */
function job_post_node_info() {
  return array(
    'job_post' => array(
      'name' => t('Job Post'),
      'base' => 'job_post',
      'description' => t('Use this content type to post a job.'),
      'has_title' => TRUE,
      'title_label' => t('Job Title'),
      'help' => t('Enter the job title and job description')
    )
  );
}

/**
 * Implement hook_form() with the standard default form.
 */
function job_post_form($node, $form_state) {
  return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
}
```

**Note:** This module example was taken from [Pro Drupal 7 Development](http://www.apress.com/9781430228387) book (page 141) with minor changes and it was given errors even with original.

Comment: Did you see http://drupal.org/node/943588 ?

Comment: Hmmm ... seem like it's Drupal's bug. We'll wait for patching. Thx

Comment: Looks like the issue has been closed/fixed with patch from http://drupal.org/node/986296#comment-3821578 though I'm not sure if this has been rolled into core v.7.12 yet.

Comment: Nope it wasn't, cos I have 7.12 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi by referring to documentation an core modules of Drupal 7. There is a usage problem.

hook_node_info defines a content type automatically. The content types which are created in this way, uninstalled-disable automatically.

Core blog module defines hook_node_info but does not operate any node_type_delete on hook_uninstall

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21blog%21blog.module/function/blog_node_info/7

When you call `node_type_delete('job_post');`  on hook_uninstall, node type info has already gone. Because of that comments module raises error.

Normally you should only remove any data related to your content type. And let the rest to be done by core.

Additionally if you really want create/delete your content type, you may not use hook_node_info. You can manually create/delete content type on install/uninstall hook.

Sample uninstall here:
http://public-action.org/content/drupal-7-field-api-drupal-7-adding-custom-content-type-custom-fields-field-api

Comment: So you're saying that we don't have to use `node_type_delete()` in our `hook_uninstall()`?

Comment: Yes, at least the proper way is that, as implemented in the core modules. But you can also copy functionality from here without invoking the other modules. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_delete/7

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the node type cache hasn't been built fully for some reason, try forcing the rebuild before you call `node_type_delete()` and all node types should be made available:

```
// Force rebuild of the node type cache
_node_types_build(TRUE);

// Delete our content type
node_type_delete('job_post');
```

Comment: It didn't help. Please see my updated question with full module's code.

Comment: You're still not calling `_node_types_build(TRUE)` in the `hook_uninstall()` function, have you tried that?

Comment: Sure do! But it didn't help anyway. Try reproduce it in your site and you'll see. Comment module should be enabled.